# Possible to add video to Odoo snippets?

Tags: video, iframe, odoo, blogs, odoo-9

I'm trying to create a snippet so the user can drag a video into a blog post. There doesn't seem to be any other way to add videos to blog posts.

I added the code to create the snippet:

```
<template id="s_blog_video" name="Blog Video">
  <section class="video-wrapper">
    <iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID" width="560"></iframe>
  </section>
</template>
```

And the code to add it to the block:

```
<template id="snippets_content" inherit_id="website.snippets">
  <xpath expr="//div[@id='snippet_structure']/div[@class='o_panel_body']" position="inside">
    <t t-snippet="theme.s_blog_video" t-thumbnail="/theme/static/src/img/ui/generic-book.png"/>
  </xpath>
</template>
```

But when I click edit, the snippets block just continually says loading.

Is it impossible to add videos to snippets? Is there any other way to add videos to blog posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add videos to blog posts.

Just add a block with an image. Then move your mouse over the added image and click on change. Select the video tab and parse a youtube link in the input fields. Save.

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked such an easy solution. Two of us were working on this problem and didn't even notice the tabs. Thanks for such an obvious answer!